# JavaScript not being executed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

so I have this [website](http://www.snoutnet.com) which just launched recently as a "coming soon" website. I have tested it among different devices and yet realized that the javascript, which handles the menu + fading in Text Elements does not work at all on Firefox. Unfortunately I don't get any Error logs.

Here is the js code:

```
$(function(){
  window.onscroll = function(e) {handleScrollActions(e)};

  var $nav = $('header');
  var $logo = $('nav img');
  var $start = $('#start');
  var $deinesgleichen = $('#netzwerk');
  var $deinesgleichen_text = $('#netzwerk-promo .text-wrapper');
  var $dogaction = $('#dogaction');
  var $dogaction_text = $('#dogaction-promo .text-wrapper');
  var $barfgenerator = $('#barfgenerator');
  var $barfgenerator_text = $('#barfgenerator-promo .text-wrapper');
  var $new_text = $('#new-promo .promo-text');
  var $flying_dog = $('.flying-dog');
  var $newsletter = $('#newsletter');

  var $walker1 = $('.walker1');
  var $walker2 = $('.walker2');
  var $walker3 = $('.walker3');
  var $walker4 = $('.walker4');

  var $join = $('.join-now');
  $join.on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
  })
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
    var hash = location.hash;
    var target = hash + "-promo";
    var to = $(target).offset().top == 0 ? 0 : $(target).offset().top - 140;
    if(window.innerWidth < 730){
      $('.mobile').slideToggle(300);
    }
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: to
    }, 1000);
    $('#init-arrow').hide();
  });

  function handleScrollActions(e){
    var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
    // console.log("Scroll Y" + scrollY);
    if(scrollY > 0){
      // $logo.attr('src', '/imgs/logo-fixed.png');
      $nav.addClass("fixed");
      // $('.video-section').css("margin-top", "42px");
    }
    if(scrollY <= 0){
      $logo.attr('src', '/imgs/logo-neu.png');
      $nav.removeClass("fixed");
      // $('.video-section').css("margin-top", "72px");
    }
    if(window.innerWidth <= 1060){
      // console.log("KLEINER ALS 1060");
      if(scrollY < 200){
        $start.addClass("active");
        $deinesgleichen.removeClass("active");
        $dogaction.removeClass("active");
        $barfgenerator.removeClass("active");
        $newsletter.removeClass("active");
        if( window.innerWidth > 1170 ){
          $('#init-arrow').show();
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(scrollY < 320){
        $start.addClass("active");
        $deinesgleichen.removeClass("active");
        $dogaction.removeClass("active");
        $barfgenerator.removeClass("active");
        $newsletter.removeClass("active");
        if( window.innerWidth > 1170 ){
          $('#init-arrow').show();
        }
      }
    }
    if( window.innerWidth <= 1170 ){
      var arrowY = 330;
    }else{
      var arrowY = 400;
    }
    if(scrollY > arrowY){
      $('#init-arrow').hide();
    }
    if( window.innerWidth <= 1060 ){
      var netzY = 200;
      var netzY2 = 520;
    }else if ( window.innerWidth <= 1170 ){
      var netzY = 321;
      var netzY2 = 720;
    }
    else{
      var netzY = 321;
      var netzY2 = 800;
    }
    if(scrollY >= netzY && scrollY <= netzY2){
      $('#init-arrow').hide();
      // location.hash != '#netzwerk' ? location.hash = '#netzwerk' : false;
      if(!$deinesgleichen_text.hasClass("animated")){
        $deinesgleichen_text.addClass("animated fadeIn text-wrapper-show");
      }

      $start.removeClass("active");
      $deinesgleichen.addClass("active");
      $dogaction.removeClass("active");
      $barfgenerator.removeClass("active");
      $newsletter.removeClass("active");
    }
    if( window.innerWidth <= 1060 ){
      var dactionY = 521;
      var dactionY2 = 900;
    }else if ( window.innerWidth <= 1170 ){
      var dactionY = 500;
      var dactionY2 = 1000;
    }
    else{
      var dactionY = 800;
      var dactionY2 = 1100;
    }
    if(scrollY >= dactionY && scrollY <= dactionY2){
      // location.hash != '#dogaction' ? location.hash = 'dogaction' : false;
      if(!$dogaction_text.hasClass("animated")){
        $dogaction_text.addClass("animated fadeIn text-wrapper-show");
      }

      $start.removeClass("active");
      $deinesgleichen.removeClass("active");
      $dogaction.addClass("active");
      $barfgenerator.removeClass("active");
      $newsletter.removeClass("active");
    }
    if( window.innerWidth <= 1060 ){
      var barfY = 911;
      var barfY2 = 1200;
    }else if ( window.innerWidth <= 1170 ){
      var barfY = 1101;
      var barfY2 = 1200;
    }
    else{
      var barfY = 1200;
      var barfY2 = 1674;
    }
    if(scrollY >= barfY && scrollY <= barfY2){
      // location.hash != '#barfgenerator' ? location.hash = '#barfgenerator' : false;
      if(!$barfgenerator_text.hasClass("animated")){
        $barfgenerator_text.addClass("animated fadeIn text-wrapper-show");
      }

      $start.removeClass("active");
      $deinesgleichen.removeClass("active");
      $dogaction.removeClass("active");
      $barfgenerator.addClass("active");
      $newsletter.removeClass("active");
    }
    if( window.innerWidth <= 1060 ){
      var lpromoY = 1201;
    }else if ( window.innerWidth <= 1170 ){
      var lpromoY = 1401;
    }
    else{
      var lpromoY = 1675;
    }
    if(scrollY >= lpromoY){
      // location.hash != '#new' ? location.hash = '#new' : false;
      if(!$new_text.hasClass("animated")){
        $new_text.addClass("animated slideInUp text-wrapper-show");
      }
      $flying_dog.addClass("animated slideInUp flying-dog-show floating");

      $start.removeClass("active");
      $deinesgleichen.removeClass("active");
      $dogaction.removeClass("active");
      $barfgenerator.removeClass("active");
      $newsletter.addClass("active");
      animateWalker3();
      animateWalker2();
      animateWalker1();
      animateWalker4();
    }
  }

  function animateWalker2(){
    $walker2.animate({right: window.innerWidth - 40}, 12000, function(){
      $walker2.css('transform','rotateY('+180+'deg)');
      $walker2.animate({left: 0}, 10000, function(){
        $walker2.css('transform','rotateY('+0+'deg)');
          animateWalker2();
      });
    });
  }
  function animateWalker1(){
    $walker1.animate({right: window.innerWidth - 80}, 13000, function(){
      $walker1.css('transform','rotateY('+180+'deg)');
      $walker1.animate({right: 0}, 10000, function(){
        $walker1.css('transform','rotateY('+0+'deg)');
          animateWalker1();
      });

    });
  }
  function animateWalker3(){
    $walker3.animate({left: window.innerWidth - 80}, 11000, function(){
      $walker3.css('transform','rotateY('+180+'deg)');
      $walker3.animate({left: 0}, 10000, function(){
        $walker3.css('transform','rotateY('+0+'deg)');
          animateWalker3();
      });

    });
  }
  function animateWalker4(){
    $walker4.animate({right: window.innerWidth - 40}, 9000, function(){
      $walker4.css('transform','rotateY('+180+'deg)');
      $walker4.animate({right: 0}, 10000, function(){
        $walker4.css('transform','rotateY('+0+'deg)');
          animateWalker4();
      });

    });
  }

  var top_login_button = document.querySelector('.promo-login-button');
  var login_wrap = document.querySelector('.login-wrap2');
  var darkbg = document.querySelector('.darkbg');

  top_login_button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    darkbg.style.display = "block";
    login_wrap.style.display = "block";
    $('.login-wrap2').addClass("animated");
    $('.login-wrap2').addClass("fadeIn");
  });

  $('#closelogin').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    darkbg.style.display = "none";
    $('.login-wrap2').removeClass("fadeIn");
    $('.login-wrap2').addClass("fadeOut");
    setTimeout(function(){
      login_wrap.style.display = "none";
      $('.login-wrap2').removeClass("fadeOut");
    },200);
  });
  darkbg.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    darkbg.style.display = "none";
    $('.login-wrap2').removeClass("fadeIn");
    $('.login-wrap2').addClass("fadeOut");
    setTimeout(function(){
      login_wrap.style.display = "none";
      $('.login-wrap2').removeClass("fadeOut");
    },200);
  })
  var mobile_menu = $('.mobile-menu');
  mobile_menu.on("click", function(e){
    $('.mobile').slideToggle(300);
  });
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){
    // console.log(window.innerWidth);
    if(window.innerWidth > 730){
      document.querySelector('.mobile').style.display = "flex";
      // $('.mobile').style.display = "block";
    }else{
      document.querySelector('.mobile').style.display = "none";
    }

  });

  var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
  setInterval(function () {
    // console.log(vid.currentTime);
    if(vid.currentTime > 7){
      vid.currentTime = 0;
      // console.log("video reseted");
    }
  }, 1000);

  function hashOnce(e){
      var hash = location.hash;
      if(hash == ""){

      }else{
        var target = hash + "-promo";
        // $('.mobile').slideToggle(300);
        var to = $(target).offset().top == 0 ? 0 : $(target).offset().top - 140;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: to
        }, 1000);
        $('#init-arrow').hide();
      }
  }
  hashOnce();

  if(localStorage.newsletter){
    $('#newsletter-signup div').remove();
    $('.success-newsletter').toggle();
  }

  var newsletter_signup = $('#newsletter-signup');
  newsletter_signup.on("submit", function(e){
    // console.log("EMIAL SIGNUP");
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    $.post('/api/signupnewsletter', {data: email}, function(result){
      // console.log(result);
      // alert("passt");
      $('#newsletter-signup div').remove();
      $('.success-newsletter').toggle();
      localStorage.newsletter = true;
    });
  });
});
```

The code is visible and not minified on the website so you can inspect it freely.

I'd appreciate any solution and hint!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: So it works in all other browsers except Firefox? Have you checked the FF console for errors? Is JavaScript enabled in your FF?

Comment: Yes its enabled and I get no errors.

Comment: @NickDelaney - I'm verifying that the OP actually tried other browsers and isn't assuming that it works in them. And the OP mentions error logs which aren't necessarily the same as the console. Do you have a problem with me verifying what the OP has tried? What he describes doesn't make much sense, hence my questions.

Comment: And this would appear to be more of a CSS/vendor prefix issue. You need to post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @noa-dev Have you verified that the handleScrollActions() method is being called when you are scrolling via console.log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox doesn't use `document.body.scrollTop` - it's always 0.

You should use `window.scrollY` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Good find, document.body.scrollTop was depracated

Comment: Ough... thank you :)